# How to grant access to IIS user

Tags: iis, ssh, sharpsvn, pageant

I'm working on a web app that uses SharpSVN to checkout from a repo using svn+ssh. I have configured my ssh client correctly in my AppData config file by adding the path to Plink under the `[tunnels]` section, but checkout requests still give me an error message. The message itself isn't particularly informative (it merely tells me to remove the -q option to better debug SSH connection issues), but I trust it's an authentication issue.

Normally in Tortoise I would just use pageant, but I don't think the IIS user has access to pageant or the keys stored on it.

Two possible solutions come to mind:

- Grant IIS user access to the pageant keys
- Fix configurations to allow direct storage of user/password inside web.config connectionString

Ideally, I'd like to use the second option, but I have yet to figure out how to get either of these to work. Does anybody have experience with using SVN over ssh in a web application?